# Remove gap between flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

In menu item, i am using display: Flex

on hover there is space between items

Used: Align-content: stretch but no result

[see image: space showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEuqg.png)

**My Code**

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.menu li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
/>
<ul
  class="menu dflx border-top-light px-10 container py-10 justify-between items-center"
>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> Explore</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i> Attractions</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i> Latest Deals </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> Menu </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's how `justify-content: space-between` works, see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Comment: please check image - on hover space showing, which i am trying to remove https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEuqg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `flex: 1; justify-content: center;` in `.menu li`

Working example

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.menu li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
/>
<ul
  class="menu dflx border-top-light px-10 container py-10 justify-between items-center"
>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> Explore</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i> Attractions</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i> Latest Deals </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> Menu </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```